# Chrome Extension API: Nesting Callbacks, No Guarantee It Is Finished Before Proceeding?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code:

```
function saveAndCallback() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        // set a few properties needed in index.bundle.js
    }, function (data) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
            file: "main.css"
        }, function(data) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                file: "index.bundle.js"
            }, function(data) {
                chrome.storage.local.get(['someString', 'someNumber'], function(data) {
                    showMatchList(data.someString, data.someNumber);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Question**

It seems `showMatchList(..)` runs before `index.bundle.js` has finished running (I set `someString` and `someNumber` there). Specifically, `someString` and `someNumber` are always one save behind.

Are we not guaranteed that the previous callback is done before firing off the next one?

According to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript):

> Callback is called after all the JavaScript has been executed.

Comment: If index.bundle.js is using timeouts or other async stuff, that code may easily run like 5 minutes later. You're using chrome.storage.local.set there, right? It's async so it may run afterwards.

Comment: The callback is invoked after the synchronous portion of the content script completes, it's the only guarantee.

Comment: Yes, thanks @wOxxOm, that answers it. Any obvious way to solve it? I need it to run after the set in the content script is done.

Comment: Use messaging instead of storage.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ugh, then I have to re-write everything around that. I have been using storage across the board. With messaging, would you somehow send an update which the non-content-script is listening for?

Comment: Hmm, you can try to switch to chrome.storage.onChanged in the popup.